# Is there a place to ask open-ended, chatty questions?

Tags: discussion

Where can I ask questions that on normal EL&U would get closed due to having far more than one answer, basing on personal opinions, polling etc?

Example: I'd like to ask about various non-obvious language resources. Things like NGram, or the free (no subscription required) gateway to OED, various little-known resources and little-known techniques of using well-known resources you use in your daily work.

Chatty, subjective, with no single correct answer, all unsuitable for EL&U but definitely something I'd like to know, and I'm pretty sure a lot of people would love such tips&resources entry.

Comment: ...I must say, I miss the old formula of StackExchange where you'd just mark a question "community wiki" and have 300 answers, all of them contributing something of value...

Comment: [Quora.com](https://quora.com) is starting to get bigger than SE.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask in the [chat room for EL&U](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage).
The chat is perfect for chatty, open-ended questions, polls, requests for opinions, and discussions. It is also less restrictive about what is acceptable, and not.

There aren't Stack Exchange sites where chatty, open-ended questions are acceptable. In all the Stack Exchange sites (but not their meta sites), the [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) says, "Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: Do inactive chats get purged, or are they retrievable?

Comment: A "chatty" question goes in the "chat room"?  Who named that anyway?

Comment: @StoneyB Inactive chat rooms that contain enough posts are frozen; the other inactive chat rooms are deleted. Only a chat moderator can unfreeze chat rooms, or undelete them.

Comment: I've just remembered that Zairja recently issued an invitation to Chat about a question, with the idea of evolving a better question. Is it *fas* to include such an invitation in the body of a question?

Comment: @StoneyB In a post, you can add the link to the chat room. Otherwise, the invitation is done with a POST form, and it is not possible to get a link to a POST form.

Comment: @StoneyB, "fas" meaning?

Comment: @Pacerier It's Latin: right, licit, 'done'

Comment: @StoneyB, Odd it neither shows up [in Google](https://google.com/search?q=define+fas) or [in OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/bware/dofind.cgi?word=fas)